# Finding cylinder mass using triple integrals

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find mass of a cylinder using triple integrals.

The data I have:

- height = $h$
- base is a circle and its radius = $a$
- the density in a point P is directly propotional to the distance of its basis.

I think that I can use $p(z) = k*z$

and that the basis formula is

$x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ (the circunference formula).

I also think that the inferior limit in $z$ integral is 0 and the superior limit is $h$.

But I can't figure out the x and y inferior and superior limits.

Someone can help me?

Comment: You should not attempt to do the integral using cartesian coordinates, you should do it using cylindrical coordinates. Cylindrical coordinates suit the geometry of the problem much better and hence will make it much easier to answer.

Comment: sadly the question asks to use cartesian coordinates. We have not learned cylindrical coordinates until now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you must use cartesian coordinates then you need to realise your cylinder is defined over $-a \leq x \leq a, -\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}, 0 \leq z \leq h$.

So your integral to calculate the mass of the cylinder will look like

\begin{equation}
\textrm{mass} = \int_{x = -a}^{x = a} \int_{y = - \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}^{y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} \int_{z = 0}^{z = h} p(z)\ dzdydx. 
\end{equation}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can understand the fact that y = sqrt(r^2 - x^2). But why x is not equaks to sqrt(r^2 - y^2)???

Comment: I mean .. Why dx dont have sqrt(r^2 - y^2) and -sqrt(r^2 - y^2) as its integral range?

Comment: @chr0x just be careful using that notation, here you should write $a$ rather than $r$, the radius $r$ is fixed at the value $a$. Generally $r$ is used to denote the radius as a function. By writing $y = \pm \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$, we've just described $y$ as a function of $x$ over the circle, we could equivalently write $x = \pm \sqrt{a^2 - y^2}$, but this wouldn't help us any further. We just write it this way to parametrize the circle in terms of only 1 variable, in this case it was x. Feel free to accept my answer if it satisfies your question :)

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your explanation and for your patience. I will fix the notation.

Comment: Glad to help :)